# How to get only a subset of an ordered hash in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, hash

Let's take this example:

```
d = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4}
```

Since hashes are now ordered, I might want to get data from `a` to `b` or from `c` to `d`. The problem is that I can't do `d[0..1]` or `d[2..3]`.

I could however do:

```
irb > d.to_a[0..1]
=> [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

... but this feels messy and I don't want to cast my hash for an operation like this.

Is there a cleaner solution to handle this?

```
# Holy Grail
irb > d[0..1]
=> {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
```

I can see how to program myself such a method, but there might be something native already done that I could use...?

Comment: A range could also be a valid hash key, so you'll have to use a custom method for this. I don't think there is nothing built-in, btw.

Answer (score 7):

Well you could do :

```
> a = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4}
> a.slice(*a.keys[0..1])
=> {"a" => 1, "b" => 1}
```

At least the hash is not cast, but it's still not very elegant in my opinion.

Comment: It'd be more elegant if you simply wrap that up in some kind of method patched on to Hash.

Comment: this is a sound way, but you still have to get all the keys of the hash. But if the implementation does not support slicing the hash by the index it's hard to find something better.

Comment: How will `Hash#values_at` be returning a hash..it will be returning the values for the keys as an array only. See [Ruby API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values_at).

Comment: My bad you're right. Then I guess the best solution is to use hash#slice as BiHi suggested, like so : a.slice(*a­.keys[0..1­])

Comment: You can use `slice` from the `facets` gem: `include "facets/hash/slice"; a.slice(*a­.keys[0..1­])`. No need to load Rails, nor the full facets.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make comparisons on the key to select the subset, you can use [`Hash#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-select), it also works in 1.8.7 but returns an array of arrays instead (as per your example).

```
d.select {|k, v| k < 'c' } # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
d.select {|k, v| k < 'c' } # 1.8.7 => [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

You can also use ActiveSupport’s Hash extension that adds a [`slice` method to Hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) that can also work, provided you already know the keys you want.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/slice'
d.slice('a', 'b') # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

Comment: In this case the OP would want a Hash#slice_by_index with all the options that Array#[] supports.

Comment: Yes, most of the time, you know the keys you want or how to select them based on a comparison, but he wants them based on the index, which is not what I answered. On top of that, my answer is bad because it uses ActiveSupport where only Hash#values_at is needed, as @DuoSRX showed.

Comment: @BiHi In my situation I want to get the keys based on their index, not their values

Answer (score 2):

Probably there's a better way to do it but this is an idea:

```
class Hash
    def slice_by_index(a, b = nil)  
        k = if a.is_a?(Range)
            keys[a]
        elsif b.nil?
            [keys[a]]
        else
            keys[a,b]
        end
        k.inject({}){|h, k| h[k] = self[k] ; h }
    end
end

h = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4}
p h.slice_by_index(1..3) #range
p h.slice_by_index(2) #single element
p h.slice_by_index(0,3) #start, lenght
```